# Confusion with Equivalence and Replacement theorems

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> Proposition: If $\psi$ is a subformula of $\phi$ and $\phi'$ results from replacing $0$ or more occurrences of $\psi$ in $\phi$ by a wf $\rho$ and each free variable of $\psi$ or $\rho$ that it's also a bound variable of $\phi$ occurs in the list $y_1,y_2,...,y_k,$ then
>
> $$a)\vdash [\forall y_1...\forall y_k(\psi\leftrightarrow\rho)]\to(\phi\leftrightarrow\phi')$$ $$b)
>  \vdash\psi\leftrightarrow\rho\implies\vdash\phi\leftrightarrow\phi'$$
>   $$c)\vdash\psi\leftrightarrow\rho,\vdash\phi\implies\vdash\phi'$$

I don't understand a) and I tried to understand it with a particular  example but I got more confused, and the only example that appears in the book is this $$a) \forall x(A_1(x)\leftrightarrow A_2(x))\implies(\exists xA_1(x)\leftrightarrow \exists A_2(x))$$ for which I still don't see the relation with the theorem a).

Could someone explain to me how I could understand these theorems? Maybe with  another kind of examples. I need to understand the proposition to solve my homework.

---

The example that I construct is this

Suppose $\phi=[\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))]\to R(y).$ Then a subformula of $\phi$ is $\psi=\{[\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x))]\to R(y),\forall x(P(x)\to Q(x)),P(x)\to Q(x),P(x),Q(x),R(y)\}$. Now I suppose  that $\psi$ have 1 ocurrence in $\phi ,$  $\phi'=\rho$. But from here I can't assume $\rho\leftrightarrow\psi$ because $\rho$ is a wf and $\psi$ is a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\psi$ (in your example), is the set of all subformula of $\phi$, i.e, a subformula is a wf this is not a set.

Now, if $\phi$ is as your example and $\rho\equiv R(y)\wedge R(y)$, then 
$$
\vdash\forall y(R(y)\leftrightarrow\rho)
$$
So, by $(a)$, you can conclude (and deduction theorem)
$$
\vdash(∀x(P(x)→Q(x))→R(y))\leftrightarrow(∀x(P(x)→Q(x))→\rho).
$$

Comment: How do you get $\vdash\forall y(R(y)\leftrightarrow\rho)$? Is it the LRS of a)?

Comment: @Michelle $A\leftrightarrow A\wedge A$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manufcature some simple but meaningful example like e.g.

> $\forall x ( x \ge 0) \to (1 \ge 0)$

as $\phi$.

We know (we can prove it) that $\forall x$ is equivalent to $\lnot \exists x \lnot$.

Thus, we have $\forall x ( x \ge 0)$ as $\psi$ and $\lnot \exists x \lnot (x \ge 0)$ as $\rho$.

The condition $\psi \leftrightarrow \rho$ is satisfied, and the part b) of the theorem allows us to conclude that:

> > $(\forall x ( x \ge 0) \to (1 \ge 0)) \leftrightarrow (\lnot \exists x \lnot ( x \ge 0) \to (1 \ge 0))$.

For part a), consider as $\psi: \forall x ( x \ge y)$ and as $\phi : \forall x ( x \ge y) \to (1 \ge y)$.

We have: $\forall y [ \forall x ( x \ge y) \leftrightarrow \lnot \exists x \lnot (x \ge y)]$, and then apply the theorem again.

---

The gist of the theorem is: we may *replace* provably *equivalent* formulas into a "context" formula without "changing the meaning".

Comment: Shouldn't be $\leftrightarrow$ instead of $\to$ in the second yellow rectangle?

Comment: For a), why can you consider $\forall x(x\ge y)$ as $\psi$? $\psi$ should be a subformula of $\phi,$ so should be $0$ instead of $ y$?