# Hilbert style: $\vdash\lnot\forall xB\to\exists x \lnot B$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> Prove $\vdash\lnot\forall xB\to\exists x \lnot B$

Knowing this  $\exists xB(x)\iff\lnot\forall x\lnot B(x)$ as definition, using Modus ponens and Generalization rule.

**Proof**

$\lnot\forall xB\iff\exists x\lnot B$ therefore $\lnot\forall xB\to\exists x \lnot B$

Is the proof correct?

Comment: What you wrote isn't at all a Hilbert style proof.  Have you ever seen one before?   Even one for propositional logic?  Could you give a Hilbert style proof for $\vdash (A \to B) \to (B \to C) \to (A \to C)$ ?

Comment: @DanielV mmh, someone told me that Mendelson logic book use the Hilbert style, and the exercise is from that book. I wrote Hilbert style since the proof that I need should not use  natural style.

Comment: Contraposing a conditional can be a useful tool to get you to a negation you're after. Also, working backward from your goal (in this case $\neg\forall x \neg B(x)) $ is almost always easier than trying to see which instance of an axiom schema you need and working forward.

Comment: The informal argument that they're logically equivalent statements and therefore one implies the other is correct, but in order to turn this into a formal proof, you need to formally prove that they are logically equivalent (and you also need to have established at some point that concluding an implication from an equivalence is a valid inference). Unrolling the definition gives $$ \lnot\forall x B \iff \lnot \forall x \lnot \lnot B$$ as the equivalence you want to prove. Although it is obvious that the double negation on the RHS should "cancel out", you need a *formal* proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to prove something with [Mendelson](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)'s system, you have to re-use previous proved results.

You need **Lemma 1.11** (a) [ [page 31](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31) ]: $\vdash \lnot \lnot  \mathcal B \to \mathcal B$, as well as **Lemma 1.11** (e) :  $\vdash (\mathcal B \to \mathcal C) \to (\lnot \mathcal C \to \lnot \mathcal B)$.

*Proof sketch*:

1) $\vdash \lnot \lnot   \mathcal B \to \mathcal B$ --- **Lemma 1.11** (b)

2) $\vdash \forall x \ (\lnot \lnot  \mathcal B \to \mathcal B)$ --- from 1) by Gen

3) $\vdash \forall x \lnot \lnot  \mathcal B \to \forall x \mathcal B$ --- from 2) by **Ex.2.27** (a) [ [page 73](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA73) ]: $\vdash \forall x \ (\mathcal B \to \mathcal C) \to (\forall x \mathcal B \to \forall x \mathcal C)$ and MP

4) $\vdash \lnot \forall x \mathcal B \to \lnot \forall x \lnot \lnot  \mathcal B$ --- from 3) and **Lemma 1.11** (e) by MP

> 5) $\vdash \lnot \forall x \mathcal B \to \exists \lnot  \mathcal B$ --- from 4) and abbreviation.

Comment: I was thinking about this exercise again and a new proof came to my mind. Is it correct?    As we have 1), then we should have $\vdash\lnot\forall x B\to\lnot\forall x \lnot\lnot B$. Therefore by definition, $\vdash\lnot\forall xB\to\exists x \lnot B$

Comment: @Michelle What do you mean by "we should have"?? Mauro justifies this inference by going formally from 1-4, explicitly justifying each step. You don't need to do it the same way he did (using a meta-theorem might be quicker, for instance) but you do need to make an actual argument about the formal system, not just hand-wave that "we should have" this inference.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen you're right, I got confused and changed the order of 1). Anyway, suppose I have $\vdash B\to\lnot\lnot B$, then what I said in my first comment it's correct?

Comment: @Michelle I said nothing about arrows not pointing the right way. I said your argument is not a formal proof, and nothing has changed in that regard...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ah I understand now, I guess there is no justification for $\vdash\lnot\forall x B\to\lnot\forall x \lnot\lnot B$ I just stated it so I'm wrong.

Comment: @Michelle Yes, study Mauro's proof carefully. It's hard to tell, but it's possible the instinct you're operating on is that somehow we should be able to replace $\lnot\lnot B$ with $B$ because they're logically equivalent. In which case the proof would be something like (1)$\lnot\forall x B \to \lnot\forall x B$ (theorem $A\to A$) (2) $B\iff \lnot\lnot B$ (theorem) (3) $\lnot\forall x B \to \lnot\forall x \lnot\lnot B$ (mystery justification) (4) conclusion (definition of $\exists$). Where you have the theorems from somewhere (or by completeness since they're instances of tautologies).

Comment: @Michelle In fact, you recently asked a question about the metatheorem that provides this mystery justification https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580353/confusion-with-equivalence-and-replacement-theorems

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen that question...was difficult to understand that theorem, using it would make the proof easier definitely. However it's a theorem that it's after this exercise, so technically I am not able to use it.

Comment: @Michelle Yep, then Mauro's or something like it adjusted to the particulars of your formal system / previous results if they're different from Mendelson's is the way to go